# How to display a Dynamic type list in ListView Xamarin Form?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am developing an application from which I am obtaining data directly from a database, these are stored inside a variable of dynamic type to later insert it in a list and be able to display it in a ListView, but at the moment of executing the application, it doesn´t show me anything on the phone. The reason why I am using a variable of Dynamic type to store the data is because the application must show in a ListView all the tables that are in the Database, even if in the future new tables are inserted into the Database.

That is the reason why I can´t leave already defined models of the structures of the tables, because I can,t know the structures of the tables that will be added in the future to the DB.

I made an example of what I'm trying to do with a Dynamic type list, but it does not show me the data on the screen. I would really appreciate it if you could help me solve it.

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        private ListView lv_inst;
        private StackLayout st_inst, stk1;

        public MainPage()
        {
            Title = "List";
            CreateGUIAsync();
        }

        public void CreateGUIAsync()
        {
            lv_inst = new ListView()
            {
                HasUnevenRows = true,
                ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(ResultCell10))
            };
            var stk_2 = new StackLayout()
            {
                Orientation = StackOrientation.Vertical,
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                Children =
                    {
                        lv_inst
                    }
            };

            st_inst = new StackLayout()
            {

                Orientation = StackOrientation.Vertical,
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                Children =
                    {
                        stk_2
                    }
            };
            Content = st_inst;
        }
        protected override async void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();
            try
            {
                lv_inst.IsVisible = false;
                List<dynamic> list = new List<dynamic>();
                dynamic dObj = new ExpandoObject();
                dObj.id = "1";
                dObj.name = "Juan";
                dObj.surname = "Moreno";
                dObj.age = "22";
                list.Add(dObj);
                lv_inst.ItemsSource = list;
                lv_inst.IsVisible = true;
            }
            catch (Exception e) { await DisplayAlert("", e.StackTrace, ""); }
        }
    }

    class ResultCell10 : ViewCell
    {
        public ResultCell10()
        {
            int heigh = 35;

            List<String> propierty = new List<string>();
            List<Label> lLabel = new List<Label>();

            propierty.Add("id");
            propierty.Add("name");
            propierty.Add("surname");
            propierty.Add("age");

            var i = 0;

            foreach (var p in propierty)
            {
                lLabel.Add(
                    new Label()
                    {
                        FontSize = 10,
                        HeightRequest = heigh,
                        WidthRequest = 60,
                        TextColor = Color.Black,
                        FontFamily = "Roboto"
                    }
                 );
                lLabel[i].SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, p);
                i++;
            }

            var stackList = new StackLayout
            {
                Padding = new Thickness(10),
                Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
            };

            foreach (var l in lLabel)
            {
                stackList.Children.Add(l);
            }
            View = stackList;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you have not shown anything dynamic in the above code.  All the fields are hard coded.  You might look at datagrid and look at ways to discover the various tables that are in the database and display them dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

not being able to use dynamic objects is mentioned in the official [Xamarin docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/internals/limitations). Keith from Wintellect, wrote a detailed article [here](https://www.wintellect.com/cant-use-dynamic-c-keyword-xamarin-ios/) which states

> Apple does not allow apps to generate executable code at runtime, because this would be a potentially major security vulnerability. Prior to iOS 8, that was the rule with no exceptions. However as of iOS 8, they loosened it up slightly. You can now dynamically load pre-compiled libraries, but they still don’t allow any form of “compilation” to take place on the device itself. You can also alter an application’s execution at runtime based on a script interpreter or similar technology—but that’s not quite the same thing.

Comment: I am developing the application for Android, likewise it does not work. I do not know if the dynamic objects also apply for Android

Comment: the dynamic types are not dynamically generated code that Xamerin docs talk about prohibiting.

Comment: ExpandoObject is not supported by Xamarin binding engine.
If you want to use dynamic objects you can create own class deriving from IDictionary<string, object> and INotifyPropertyChanged. Then in Xaml binding use square brackets

Comment: Could not the view be built in C #?
I am trying to have the labels generated dynamically as I put it in the code, depending on how many fields the table has. I do not know if in XAML i can do that

Comment: foreach (var p in propierty)
            {
                lLabel.Add(
                    new Label()
                    {
                        FontSize = 10,
                        HeightRequest = heigh,
                        WidthRequest = 60,
                        TextColor = Color.Black,
                        FontFamily = "Roboto"
                    }
                 );
                lLabel[i].SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, p);
                i++;
            }

Comment: Hey Juan yes the view can be built in C#. You don't have to use Xaml if you don't want, you can let me know if you want pointers on how to do so

Comment: Yes, I´d like you to give me some pointers on how to do that view in c #, I really don't know what is the equivalent of using brackets in c #

Comment: @JuanJesusPadronDiaz you can compare LoginPageCS vs LoginPage in the official Xamarin sample tinyurl.com/y2sj6tsp As you can see, you dont have a Xaml file, and you dont call InitializeComponent ();